# Slider Color / Snap to Ticks

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, .net-4.5

I have a slider control that I want to represent playback speed in a media player application that I am building. The code I have currently is:

```
<Slider x:Name="slrSpeed" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Minimum="1" Maximum="5" Value="3" LargeChange="1" SmallChange="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" />
```

I want it to only allow whole number values of 1-5 (so no 4.5 etc). which I thought would be doable by setting the `LargeChange` and `SmallChange` values to 1, but when I slide it I can still select part numbers.

[image: Screenshot]

I also want to change the colour of the slider, track and ticks to be a similar colour to the rest of the images I am using as buttons. Can someone point me in the right direction on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable [`IsSnapToTickEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.issnaptotickenabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When the position of a Thumb is changed and the IsSnapToTickEnabled property is set to true, the Thumb is automatically moved to the closest tick mark.

```
<Slider ... IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
```

Ticks colour you can change by setting `Foreground` but for track you'll need to change `Template` for your `Slider`. You can read more under [Slider Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256(v=vs.110).aspx)